# WebView difference in android 4.3 to 4.4

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I implemented a WebView with images taken from the web.
On Android 4.3 there's no problem.
On Android 4.4 kitkat, the displayed images are too big.
How do I solve that?

Comment: The underlying browser engine has changed from webkit to chromium. Please add relevant code to the question.

Comment: Error log: 02-18 16:47:04.311: I/chromium(31038): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported

Answer (score 9):

Kitkat Behavior changes

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

For Webview Please Refer..

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Comment: How migration from 4.3 to 4.4???

Comment: explained in developer docs in link above.

Answer (score 8):

Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces a new version of WebView that is based on Chromium. This change upgrades WebView performance and standards support for HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript to match the latest web browsers. Any apps using WebView will inherit these upgrades when running on Android 4.4 and higher.

The current performance of Android webview is so poor. ChromiumWebView gives your application early access to the newest features in Chromium, and removes the variability due to different WebView implementations in different versions of Android.

The new (chromium based) WebView is faster – so far no surprise. But looking at the numbers, the performance has really increased in several areas (like up to 354% for HTML5 Canvas or 358% for some Javascript test). So your WebView content should run way smoother and faster then before
[Old WebView vs. Chromium backed WebView](https://www.timroes.de/2013/11/23/old-webview-vs-chromium-webview/)

Comment: i have no example code

Comment: HUGE improvement in performance with 4.4 over 4.3 .  On a Galaxy Nexus with 4.3 installed, my app 'chugged' along - slow refreshes, glitchy scrolling.  You can't really debug pre-4.4 because there was no debugger to attach.  So, I used a CyanogenMod to update to 4.4 (Google only upgrades phones newer than 18months), hoping to see them same problems but have the Chrome debugger to attach.  Unfortunately, it runs just as fast as my Nexus 5, so I can't see what's slowing it down.  Huge improvement, just wish Google would allow updates older than 18 months because users would benefit.