# Below Android 4.4 Webview - loaded html <li> tag with radio button, on selection gives wrong index value

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have strange problem with Android 4.3 Webviews. I have html page with list view(`<ul><li><input type="radio"> ....... </ul>`). basically I have multiple li tags with radio button input type in it. I load that html page using WebView.

Assume that I have 20 items in the list. For instance, untill first 5 items are able to select(click) and gets the right index, but if try to select(click) 10th item in the list, I get random item index depending on page scroll.

I cant post the code/image as it is client sensitive info.

I have understand that Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces a new version of WebView that is based on Chromium. source : [WebView difference in android 4.3 to 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725969/webview-difference-in-android-4-3-to-4-4)

Same code works perfect in Android > 4.3

Not able debug and no clue what is happening, is anyone faced this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after spending a day , got it fixed by replacing `overflow: visible;` with `overflow: auto;`

[Android browser bug? div overflow scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013204/android-browser-bug-div-overflow-scrolling)  post has given me the clue